# Add 1 to variable if scrolldown and subtract 1 to variable if scrollup

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title pretty much sums it up.

How do I add 1 to a variable if the user scrolls down, and subtract 1 to the same variable if the user scrolls up.

The variable must start with 0.

EDIT: For clarification, it must **constantly** add/subtract 1 if the user is scrolling up/down, and stop adding/subtracting if the user stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var x = 0;
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'mousewheel') {
        // scroll 
        if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            // scroll down
            x++;
        }
        else {
            // scroll up
            x--;
        }
    }
    else if (event.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        if (event.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
            // scroll down
            x++;
        }
        else {
            // scroll up
            x--;
        }
    }
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dV77x/1/)

Comment: Why if show the value in the console, it is always increasing?

Comment: I seem to be noticing something strange: the values in the console for Firefox are wrong while in Chrome, it is correct. Why is this?

Comment: Also, how can I stop adding 1 if I'm at the top of the page? Like wise if I'm at the very bottom?

Comment: i think you're going to have to dive into that on your own and come back here if you have a specific question..